# Get string between first space character and '=' character

Tags: javascript, string, substr

Basically, I would like to create a Javascript function to return me the string between the first space character and '=' character.

For eg:-

```
  ABC123 Mercedes Benz = 300,000
```

The function should return me Mercedes Benz. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myStr = "ABC123 Mercedes Benz = 300,000"
myStr = / [^=]+/.exec(myStr);
alert(myStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var myStr = "ABC123 Mercedes Benz = 300,000"
var targetStr = myStr.replace(/^[^\s]*\s(.*)=.*$/, "$1")
```

The `replace` method returns a new string, so `myStr` still holds its original value, but `targetStr` has the matching portion.

Answer (score 1):

You should really post some of your own attempts rather than expect SO to do everything for you. This should work for this specific case;

```
var get_second_word = function (string){

        var p1 = string.indexOf(" "),//get position of first space
            p2 = string.indexOf("="),//get position of =
            len = p2 - p1,// length of chunk = pos of '=' - pos of first space
            chunk = string.substr(p1, len); //get the substring

            return chunk;

    },
    string = "ABC123 Mercedes Benz = 300,000",
    word = get_second_word(string);

    document.write(word);// prints 'Mercedes Benz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but

```
function getSmth(str) {
  var i = str.indexOf(' ') + 1;
  var j = str.indexOf('=');
  return str.substr(i, j - i - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getPartial(str)
{
    var partial = '';

    var io = str.indexOf(' ');
    if (io > 0)
    {
        partial = str.substring(io);
        var io2 = partial.indexOf('=');
        if (io2 > 0)
        {
            partial = partial.substring(0, io2);
        }
    }

    return partial;
}

var str = 'ABC123 Mercedes Benz = 300,000';
var partial = getPartial(str);

alert(partial);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "ABC123 Mercedes Benz = 300,000";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")+1);
var result = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("=")-1);
```